# Can i revoke a command in on_command discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have function

```
async def dedupetwo(self, message):
```

I am looking into checking if command is not spammed so i take history of messages is channel by calling

```
async for m in message.channel.history(limit=2, before=message.message):
                lastmsg = m
```

and then checking if the command is the same as the last message in that channel by

```
if lastmsg.clean_content == ctx.message.clean_content:
```

I am trying to revoke the call of that command in this stage and i couldnt find any calls able to make that.
Is there any function that would satisfy this or how should I make this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` to end the function/command if the `if` statement satisfies

```py
if lastmsg.clean_content == ctx.message.clean_content:
    return
```